# Can't pickle <class 'a class'>: attribute lookup inner class on a class failed

Tags: python-3.x, metaprogramming, pickle, metaclass

I was using PySpark to process some calls data. As you see, I added some inner classes to class `GetInfoFromCalls` dynamically by using metaclass. 
code below located in package `for_test` that existed in all nodes:

```
class StatusField(object):
    """
    some alias.
    """
    failed = "failed"
    succeed = "succeed"
    status = "status"
    getNothingDefaultValue = "-999999"


class Result(object):
    """
    Result that store result and some info about it.
    """

    def __init__(self, result, status, message=None):
        self.result = result
        self.status = status
        self.message = message

structureList = [
    ("user_mobile", str, None),
    ("real_name", str, None),
    ("channel_attr", str, None),
    ("channel_src", str, None),
    ("task_data", dict, None),
    ("bill_info", list, "task_data"),
    ("account_info", list, "task_data"),
    ("payment_info", list, "task_data"),
    ("call_info", list, "task_data")
]

def inner_get(self, defaultValue=StatusField.getNothingDefaultValue):
    try:
        return self.holder.get(self)
    except Exception as e:
        return Result(defaultValue, StatusField.failed)
        print(e)

class call_meta(type):
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, attrs):

        for name_str, type_class, pLevel_str in structureList:
            setattr(cls, name_str, type(
                name_str,
                (object,),
                {})
                )

class GetInfoFromCalls(object, metaclass = call_meta):
    def __init__(self, call_deatails):
        for name_str, type_class, pLevel_str in structureList:
            inn = getattr(self.__class__, name_str)()
            object_dict = {
                "name": name_str,
                "type": type_class,
                "pLevel": None if pLevel_str is None else getattr(self, pLevel_str),
                "context": None,
                "get": inner_get,
                "holder": self,
            }
            for attr_str, real_attr in object_dict.items():
                setattr(inn, attr_str, real_attr)
            setattr(self, name_str, inn)

        self.call_details = call_deatails
```

when I ran

```
import pickle

pickle.dumps(GetInfoFromCalls("foo"))
```

it raised error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-11-b2d409e35eb4>", line 1, in <module>
    pickle.dumps(GetInfoFromCalls("foo"))
PicklingError: Can't pickle <class '__main__.user_mobile'>: attribute lookup user_mobile on __main__ failed
```

It seemed that I can't pickle inner classes because them were added dynamically by code. When classes were pickled, inner classes were not existed, is it right?
Really I don't want to write these classes that were nearly same to each other. Does someone has good way to avoid this problem?

Comment: Upovted, because It is always good to see a MCVE, but to be honest, I cannot figure out, why on Earth, would you choose such a convoluted solution.  Especially working with Spark.

Comment: What do you mean by MCVE :) ? Because I use PySpark in jupyter notebook, I always used to use `TAB` to give me some hints, like `call_detal_info.bill_info.get()`. I know that overriding some magic methods like __getattr__() can resolve my problem, But I just want to know whether using metaclass  is feasible in the condition of pickling and unpickling？

Comment: MCVE is a [mcve] :) If you want just `.` syntax, why not use `namedtuple`? And you really want to generate classes on runtime, then I'd do it in outer scope with `type`. Same with `namedtuple` for that matter.

Comment: `namedtuple` or  `type` in module-scope has same problem unless I write code like `s = type("s", (object, ), {})`. And it's not what I really concerned :).

Answer (score 7):

Python's pickle actually does not serializes classes: it does serialize instances, and put in the serialization a reference to each instance's class - and that reference is based on the class being bound to a name in a well defined module. So, instances of classes that don't have a module name, but rather live as attribute in other classes, or data inside lists and dictionaries, typically will not work.

One straight forward thing one can try to do  is try to use  [`dill`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill) instead of pickle. It is a third party package that works like "pickle" but has extensions to actually serialize arbitrary dynamic classes.

While using `dill`  may help other people reaching here, it is not your case, because in order to use dill, you'd have to monkey patch the underlying RPC mechanism PySpark is using to make use of dill instead of pickle, and that might not be trivial nor consistent enough for production use.

If the problem is really about dynamically created classes being unpickable, what you can do is to create extra meta-classes, for the dynamic classes themselves, instead of using "type", and on these metaclasses, create proper `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` (or other helper methods as it is [on pickle documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)) - that might enable these classes to be pickled by ordinary Pickle. That is, a separate metaclass with Pickler helper methods to be used instead of `type(..., (object, ), ...)` in your code.

However, "unpickable object" is not the error you are getting - it is an attribute lookup error, which suggests the structure you are building is not good enough for Pickle to introspect into it and get all the members from one of your instances - it is not related (yet) to the unpickleability of the class object. Since your dynamic classes live as attributes on the class (which is not itself pickled) and not of the instance, it is very well possible that pickle does not care about it. Check the docs on pickle above, and maybe all you need there is proper helper-method to pickle on you class, nothing different on the the metaclass for all that you have there to work properly.

Comment: Great answer! Thank you :)